# Как разделить массив значений на заданное количество групп

Tags: java

Например, есть вот такой код

```java
 final List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11);
        final int chunkSize = 3;
        final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

        final Collection<List<Integer>> result = numbers.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> counter.getAndIncrement() / chunkSize))
                .values();

        System.out.println(result);
```

или такой

```java
 List<String> originalList = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3",
                "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11");

        int partitionSize = 3;

        List<List<String>> partitions = new LinkedList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < originalList.size(); i += partitionSize) {

            int min = Math.min(i + partitionSize, originalList.size());
            partitions.add(originalList.subList(i, min ));
        }

        System.out.println(partitions);
```

Но в них происходит создание отдельных массивов в которые помещается заданное количество элементов.

Но задача состоит в том, чтобы поделить массив таким образом (массив имеет N-длину), чтобы можно было поместить в него равномерно количество элементов из оригинального массива.

Например, есть массив файлов из 16 файлов, нужно разбить оригинальный массив на 3 группы и  нужно из этого массива произвести копирование некоторого количества файлов в эти 3 группы равномерно.
В первой группе например, будет 5 элементов, во второй 5 элементов, а в 3-й 6 элементов ....

```java
File[] files = sourceFolder.listFiles();

File[] filesFirstArr = divideArray(files, ?,  ?);

    public static File[] divideArray(File[] filesOrigin, int posCopySource , int sizeArrayFiles){

        File[] filesPart = new File[sizeArrayFiles];
        System.arraycopy(filesOrigin, posCopySource, filesPart, 0, sizeArrayFiles);

        return filesPart;
    }
```

Вызов этого метода будет происходить в цикле, например, так

```java
File[] files = sourceFolder.listFiles();

for(int i = 0; i < sourceFolder.length(); i += partitionSize){
...
}
```

Не могу понять, как найти вычислить величину позиции копирования элементов (начальную, для каждой новой группы элементов) и не могу понять как вычислить очередной размер массива, очередной группы элементов)

У кого есть идеи, как это сделать ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> как вычислить очередной размер массива, очередной группы элементов

```java
int partitionSize = files.length / numberOfChunks;
int rest = files.length % numberOfChunks;

// Принимаем решение о том, что делать с неполным остатком
boolean includeRest = rest < partitionSize / 2;

// уменьшаем количество итераций на одну, если нужно
int bound = sequence.length - (includeRest ? partitionSize : 0);
for(int i = 0; i < bound; i += partitionSize){
    boolean isLastChunk = (i + partitionSize) >= bound;
    File[] chunk = Arrays.copyOfRange(files, i,
          (isLastChunk && includeRest)
              ? files.length
              : Math.min(files.length, i + partitionSize));
    // ...
}
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/B1SE7ziKP)

Comment: Files[] - опечатка. Нужно -   File[], так как это 2 разных класса.

Comment: Да, разумеется. В остальном ответ вам подошёл?

Comment: да. Отлично подошел. Спасибо.

Comment: vp_arth - просьба посмотрите переработанное решения, я там оставил комментарии. Правильно ли я понял ход ваших мыслей ?

Comment: Да вроде всё верно. Только зря вы в вопрос ответ добавили. Вопрос должен оставаться вопросом, тут не форум, а что-то вроде QA базы знаний. Вопросы в вопросах, ответы в ответах =)

Comment: Мне отдельный сделать здесь же ?

Comment: Если считаете нужным, да. Смотрите с точки зрения, будет ли этот код полезным тем, кто столкнётся с такой же проблемой и придёт сюда из поисковика)

Comment: ну этот код нужен был чтобы разделить для потоков обработку файлов в одном большом каталоге, я  что-то не нашел похожего решения, хотя может плохо искал

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116203/discussion-between-skyho-and-vp-arth).

Answer (score 0):

**Обновление** (основано на предложенном решении, участника форума -  vp_arth )

```java
 public static void main(String[] args){

        int partitionSize = 3;

        FileWriteRepository fileWriteRepository = new FileWriteRepositoryImpl();
        String srcFolder = "source";
        File sourceFolder = fileWriteRepository.getPathDirToSource(srcFolder);

        File[] files = sourceFolder.listFiles();

        List<File[]> dividingFiles = runDividingFiles(files, partitionSize);
}

private static List<File[]> runDividingFiles(File[] files, int numberOfChunks){

        List<File[]> resultArr = new ArrayList<>();

        /*количество файлов в одном сегменте*/
        int partitionSize = files.length / numberOfChunks;

        /*получаем размер последнего неполного сегмента*/
        int rest = files.length % numberOfChunks;

        /*получаем половину одного сегмента*/
        int halfOneSegment = partitionSize / 2;

        /*проверяем, нужно ли включать остаток в текущий собираемый массив*/
        boolean includeRest = false;

        if(rest > 0 && rest <= halfOneSegment) includeRest = true;

        /* уменьшаем количество итераций на одну, если нужно*/
        int bound = files.length - (includeRest ? partitionSize : 0);

        /*каждый цикл формируем новый массив файлов, который представляет собой
         * один из сегментов оригинального большого массива*/
        for (int i = 0; i < bound; i += partitionSize) {

            /*вычисляем минимальное значение, между длиной массива и текущим последним
             * индексом создаваемого сегмента*/
            int min = Math.min(files.length, i + partitionSize);

            /* Проверяем, нужно ли включать остаток в последний сегмент*/

            boolean isLastChunk = false;

            if((i + partitionSize) >= bound){
                isLastChunk = true;
            }

            int endIndexRange;

            /*определяем последний индекс файла в текущем создаваемом сегменте*/
            if (includeRest && isLastChunk) {

                endIndexRange = files.length; /*если в сегментах четное число файлов*/
            } else {
                endIndexRange = min;
            }

            File[] filesResult = Arrays.copyOfRange(files, i, endIndexRange);

            resultArr.add(filesResult);
        }

        return resultArr;
    }
```